# What's the output? BODMAS?

Tags: java, math, expression, operator-precedence

Can someone please explain in what order will the compiler evaluate the following expression. The result comes out to 30, but I cannot figure how.
According to BODMAS, if I'm correct, the brackets should be evaluated first, then division, then multiplication followed by addition and subtraction. But this order does not give me the correct answer.

```
public static void main(String args[] ) {
    int a = 30 - 12 / (2 * 5 ) + 1;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. The multiplication has to happen first (because it's in the brackets). 2*5 is 10. 12/10 is 1 (using integer arithmetic). 30 - 1 + 1 is 30. What do you expect the result to be and why? How would you expect the division to happen *before* multiplication, given that the RHS of the division operator contains the multiplication, within brackets?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of operator precedence is correct. Let's break this expression down step by step:

Original expression:

```
30 - 12 / (2 * 5 ) + 1;
```

First, the brackets are evaluated:

```
30 - 12 / 10 + 1;
```

Then, according to operator precedence, `*`, `/` and `%` operations are evaluated. In your case, you only have a `/` operator. Note that the two operands are **int**s, so `/` will perform [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), returning only the "whole" part of the result, i.e. `1`:

```
30 - 1 + 1;
```

No we evaluate `+`s and `-`s from left to right:

```
29 + 1;

30;
```

Comment: It was the "whole" part that I was messing up. Thanks for clarifying Mureinik!

Answer (score 1):

According to **BODMAS**, answer should be 30.

```
int a = 30 - 12 / (2 * 5 ) + 1;
```

> Brackets evaluated first - `2*5 = 10`
>
> Division next - `12/10 - 1`
>
> Addition/Subtraction - `30 -1 + 1`

**Answer - 30**

Comment: Oh of course! I was being dumb and was calculating 12/10 as 1.2 :/
Thanks Ankur!